# TensorFlow Lite Model stolen by reverse engineering

Tags: android, tensorflow, reverse-engineering

I made an app that uses a TensorFlow Lite model, therefore I've put it in the assets folder.

I have noticed that it's the easiest thing on earth to reverse engineer my app to get that model:

- just download the apk
- make it a zip file and extract it
- in the assets folder you then see my model and can use it however you want

---

What way is there to make it at least harder to steal my model? And then, how would hackers be able to steal it still?

Comment: Reverse engineering is hard, what you describe is just taking a file; that is not hard and also not reverse engeneering.

Answer (score 1):

- You can encrypt the file on disk
- Load the encryption key on runtime (like joining a list of chars...)
- Decrypt model file on runtime and load it
- set `minifyEnabled` to `true` in `build.gradle` so your code gets minified and obfuscated.